# swift 4 Timer to start at specific time, then do the interval

Tags: swift, timer

I want to call a method at the same time every day (at the end of the day, like 23.59).
I understand to set a repeating method to be called I do like this:

```
let date = Date()
let timer = Timer(fireAt: date, interval: 86400, target: self, selector: 
#selector(runCode), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)
```

This repeats every 86400 seconds, which mean every day.
But how to set the date parameter to start at 23.59, the specific time I want. Currently, it just goes off at the time the code calls it.

Thanks very much

Comment: There's no sense in creating a timer with an interval of 1 day. It will only work if the user keeps your app running in the foreground for that entire day.

Comment: Does this method not get called if the app is closed, or in background?

Comment: No, the user isn't using your app, the timer won't run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like you might have to do silent notifications:

[Silent Push Notification Payload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36323903/silent-push-notification-payload?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

[What is difference between remote notification and silent notification in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42275060/what-is-difference-between-remote-notification-and-silent-notification-in-ios/42275137?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

There is also a UNNotifcationRequest you can look into but it's not silent:

[Use UNNotificationRequest (UserNotificationFramework) for data only local notification on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46002528/use-unnotificationrequest-usernotificationframework-for-data-only-local-notifi?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)